# PHP GCM 1000 users loop

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send in a loop a message through GCM in order to bypass the bulk limit that google has.

I have found some answers in here that were very helpful and this is the final php code that I use in order to send in bulk messages to the registered users in my database.

However the process stops after 1000 and i get the message 
Number of messages on bulk (1016) exceeds maximum allowed (1000)

Can someone see whats wrong with the following code?

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'connect.php';

function send_notification($con,$registatoin_ids, $message) { 
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$msg = array
(
'message'   => "the message",
'title'     => 'my title',
'subtitle'  => 'subtitle. subtitle',
'msgcnt'    => 3,
'vibrate'   => 1,
'sound'     => 'default',
'soundname' => 'beep.wav',
'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
'registration_ids'  => $registatoin_ids,
  'data'            => $msg
);

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . apiKey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;

}

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {   
$num=$con->query("SELECT gcm_regid from gcm_users")->rowCount();
$current_num=0;
$message=$_POST["message"];
for($i=0;$i<$num/1000;$i++){

$query=$con->query("SELECT gcm_regid from gcm_users LIMIT    $current_num,1000");

foreach($query as $data) {
$row[]=$data["gcm_regid"];
}

$pushStatus = send_notification($con,$row, $message);
$current_num+=1000;
}
}else if(isset($_POST["logout"])){

if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{
header("Location: login.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
}

?>
```

thank you

Comment: I'd check the size of the $row array that you are passing to send_notification. Could you confirm that it's size is 1000

Comment: yes it is. I tried changing 1000 to 500, but in the end i get the same error message: Number of messages on bulk (1035) exceeds maximum allowed (1000)

Answer (score 2):

You can ONLY send 1000 emails per request using GCM. Split Your users with chunking them into smaller chunks(lets say 500 users per chunk: `$current_num,500`) and send emails to them in 2 or more requests.

Comment: Thnx for your answer, I knew that i can only send 1000 per request, in my code I tried to do that but with no result. Can you see whats wrong in the code above? thnx again